# When labeling people in a picture, should I label them as they were or as they are at present?

Tags: meaning, ambiguity

Let's say I am labeling a picture of me, my wife and my stepson, but the picture is of an occasion before we got married. 
Is it misleading to label the picture: "me, my wife and my stepson" which is true now, but was not true at the time the picture was taken?
Edit:  Let's say in the context of a picture album that subsequently included our wedding pictures?

Comment: I have a picture of my mother when she attended school in the early 1930s, Mussolini era, I wasn't born but when I show the photo to friends I tell them "That's my mum when she was a girl" Likewise you could say "That's Jack, my stepson when he was 15 years old" or "two years ago."

Answer (score 2):

You can label the picture (photo)

> Me, my future wife, and her son

which makes it clear when it was made (taken), requiring no explanation.

Comment: So would you say it could potentially be somewhat misleading or cause confusion it the label simply said Me, my wife and my stepson?  Let's say in the context of a picture album that subsequently included our wedding pictures?

Comment: As in the question, it would be misleading because it wasn't true, and requires explanation. But my suggestion tells the full story, making it clear he is *her* son, and implying that she is now your wife and he is your step-son.

Comment: In the context of a larger album it might be better just to use their names, especially if pictures of the wedding are included. The change in relationship would be self-evident if it's arranged chronologically.

Comment: Well, the reader of my album will be a government officer who only knows  "petitioner" and "beneficiary" or "petitioner's wife" and "beneficiary's son" and "petitioner's step-son" and is unlikely to know or care about names.

Answer (score 2):

It's not quite *wrong* to label it that way, but it might be best to add a clarification:

> me, my wife and my stepson, before the marriage

Another option is to say:

> me and my now wife and stepson

(with the extra "and" added so the one "now" applies to both wife and stepson). See the [Wiktionary entry](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/now#Adjective), particularly the 1908 example under "quotations" for adjective meaning 1.